# Utility functions for recursive arrays

Tags: javascript

I stopped using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) to become better at JavaScript. These are recursive utility functions to deal with nested arrays:

```
const _ = {}

// find object in nested arrays
_.findDeep = (arr, obj) => {
  return arr.map(item => {
    const key = _.keys(obj)[0]
    if (item[key] === obj[key]) return arr
    if (item.children) return _.findDeep(item.children, obj)
    return undefined
  }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev || curr
  })
}

// insert new object above an object in nested array
_.insertUpDeep = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  let found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) found.splice(found.indexOf(obj), 0, newObj)
  return arr
}

// TODO rename this into something less suggestive
_.insertDownDeep = (arr, obj, newObj) => {
  let found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) found.splice(found.indexOf(obj) + 1, 0, newObj)
  return arr
}

// same as the two above, but create a container for the
// two objects so they can have their own flow. e.g.
// flex-direction: row/column
_.insertLeftDeep = (arr, bj, newObj, contObj) => {
  let found = _.findDeep(arr, obj)
  if (found) {
    contObj.children.push(obj)
    contObj.children.push(newObj)
    found.splice(found.indexOf(obj), 0, contObj)
    found.splice(found.indexOf(obj), 1) // to avoid duplicating obj
  }
  return arr
}

export default _
```

Example input:

```
const colors = {
   name: 'orange'
   children: [{
     name: 'white'
   }, {
     name: 'green',
     children: [{
       name: 'yellow',
       children: [{
         name: 'red'
       }, {
         name: 'white'
       }]
     }, {
       name: 'green',
       children: [{
         name: 'purple',
         color: 'purple',
         path: 'writer'
       }]
     }]
   }, {
     name: 'gray'
   }]
 }

 const color = {
   name: 'brown'
 }

 const newColor = {
   name: 'white'
 }

 const container = {
   name: 'container'
   children: [
     color
   ]
 }

 insertUpDeep(colors, color, newColor)
 insertLeftDeep(colors, color, newColor, container)
```

I would like to know how to 1) make it simpler/easier to read 2) make it flexible as modularized as Lodash functions.

(I'm specially concerned about the number of parameters that `insertLeftDeep` has. It's easy to forget which arguments it's supposed to have.)